# What do I do if a key fob is stuck in my driver side door at about a 45 degree angle

Tags: ford, key, locks

My wife's car, a 2010 Ford Flex had a dead battery recently.  We got the battery replaced fine, but during the ordeal, her keyfob would not work.  So she used the the key in the side door.  When she did, it got stuck at about a 45 degree tilt to the right.  The key now will not turn in any direction and cannot be removed from the door.  We can get the doors open and drive the car with the spare keyfob, but we are stuck with the key hanging out the door.  We have had people from the auto parts store look at it as well as a locksmith.  Jiggling, pulling, tapping, pushing, etc...  does not seem to loosen the key at all.

At this point we are headed to the dealership, but I wanted to ask what could have caused it, and what to look for.  I don't want the dealership to charge me for some new part that I do not need.  Is there something I should have tried to get the key out?

Comment: Check and see if the lock cylinder is easy to remove on a lot of newer cars the cylinder and trim are only held in place by a t30 screw.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!